# Assigning a selector via SEL type?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I just spotted the following in an online tutorial. It showed 001 as a method for assigning a selector, however I could not get this to work. Am I right in thinking that 001 is not right and 002 is the correct way, or am I doing something wrong with 001?

```
// 001
SEL mySel = [self something];

// 002  
SEL mySel = @selector(something);
```

.

```
-(void)something {
    NSLog(@"YAY");
}
```

Gary

Comment: Post the url for the online tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not necessarily an error. As pointed out, 001 is the syntax for calling a method. That said, methods can return a selector just fine, so 001 is valid only if -something on self returns a SEL.

Your definition of -something though doesn't, so in this respect 001 is an error in the tutorial if that's how they defined -something.

Comment: So for example: `-(SEL) something { return @selector(somethingElse:) ; }` would be a valid method in 001.

Comment: Hi Jer / JeremyP, perfect, the error is mine I was miss understanding and thinking that SEL was a pointer to the method. I now understand that the first example needs a method that returns a SEL.

Answer (score 1):

001 is the syntax for calling something (sending something to self).

002 is correct for assigning to a SEL object.

Seems like an error in that tutorial to me.